# using rep() in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, rep

How can I repeat the integers 1:20 in a vector 20 times each?

i want something like

```
s <- 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3 etc.....
```

(except 20 1's then 20 2's then 20 3's.... you get the idea)

I am trying this

```
l <- 1:20
S <- for(i in l) rep(i, 20)
```

an one liner would be awesome, something like this

```
S <- for (i in 1:20, rep(i, 20))
```

but I am struggling.

thanks,

Jesse

Comment: `rep` has an `each=` argument - `rep(1:20, each=20)`

Comment: correct... didnt find that one... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

so the answer is definitely

```
s <- as.numeric(rep(1:20, each = 20))
```

but what if I wanted to do something like this

```
y <- 3500, 3750, 4000, 4250.... 6000
```

would

```
y <- 3250 + rep(250, 11)
```

work?

Answer as best I could make it...

```
a <- rep(1:20, each=8000)
b <- rep(rep(1:20, each=400), 20)
c <- rep(rep(rep(1:20, each=20), 20), 20)
d <- rep(1:20, 8000)

df <- cbind(a,b,c,d)
```

this should be a unique combination of the integers 1:20 in a 4 by 160000 matrix....

Comment: rather, why do i get 3500 11 times?

Comment: You don't need `as.numeric`. For the second case, you can use `seq(3500,6000,by=250)`

Comment: thanks Julian, just that as.numeric removed the L after every integer....

Comment: Would it work? Why don't you try it first? :)

Comment: rather... I did... why doesnt it work?